IntelliJ 2024.2 Logfile support not working
I am using the new PhpStorm 2024.2 and I was trying to test the log file support highlights. I have installed the new version of PhpStorm. Have anybody any idea, how to fix it? I would love to use this feature. Because as far as I know, we developer love errors.
P.S.
I have checked for the correct version of PhpStorm.
I have done the "File -> Invalidate Caches..." and restarted the program.

What do you do exactly and what happens? What is the expected result? Are there any error messages in the UI?
